# howmany() Macro Objective C

Tags: objective-c, c, macros, darwin

While using Xcode, I accidentally auto completed to the macro `howmany(x,y)` and traced it to `types.h`. The entire line reads as follows:

```
#define howmany(x, y)   __DARWIN_howmany(x, y)  /* # y's == x bits? */
```

This didn't really make much sense, so I followed the path a little more and found `__DARWIN_howmany(x, y)` in `_fd_def.h`. The entire line reads as follows:

```
#define __DARWIN_howmany(x, y)  ((((x) % (y)) == 0) ? ((x) / (y)) : (((x) / (y)) + 1)) /* # y's == x bits? */
```

I have no idea what `__DARWIN_howmany(x, y)` does. Does the comment at the end of the line shed any light on the intended function of this macro? Could someone please explain **what this macro does, how it is used, and its relevance in `_fd_def.h`**

Comment: http://www.daemon-systems.org/man/howmany.9.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you've posted, the macro seems to be intended to answer a question like, "How many `char`s does it take to hold 18 bits?"  That question could be answered with this line of code

```
int count = howmany( 18, CHAR_BIT );
```

which will set `count` to 3.

The macro works by first checking if `y` divides evenly into `x`.  If so, it returns `x/y`, otherwise it divides `x` by `y` and rounds up.

Comment: but, based on the definition above, howmany(18, sizeof(char)) will yield the result 18 and not 3! howmany(x,y) seems to be equivalent to ((x-1)/(y)+1). sizeof(char) is 1, btw, and never 8.

Comment: @Michael Yes, you are correct, thanks for pointing that out. It should have been `CHAR_BIT`, not `sizeof(char)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly commonly used macro to help programmers quickly answer the question, if I have some number of things, and my containers can each hold y of them, how many containers do I need to hold x things?

So if your containers can hold five things each, and you have 18 of them:

```
  n = howmany(18, 5);
```

will tell you that you will need four containers. Or, if my buffers are allocated in words, but I need to put n characters into them, and words are 8 characters long, then:

```
  n = howmanu(n, 8);
```

returns the number of words needed. This sort of computation is ubiquitous in buffer allocation code.

This is frequently computed:

#define howmany(x, y) (((x)+(y)-1)/(y))

Also related is roundup(x, y), which rounds x up to the next multiple of y:

#define roundup(x, y) (howmany(x, y)*(y))